# fs.writeFileSync windows nodejs corrupt data(json)

Tags: node.js, azure

We are using fs.writeFileSync to write the JSON data, it seems to be working perfectly fine except one of the windows server deployed in Azure.

Following is the corrupt file data.

`{"abcid": {"name": "abc", "metadata": {}}"metadata": {}}`

We are using Node Version 4.4.2. Not sure if it has to do anything with platform(win/linux) but I have found one of the nodejs issue on github. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1058

Comment: You might want to include the code that reproduces the error. Also, the issue you link to seems to have to do with append mode - you are not appending to JSON files, are you?

Comment: No I am not appending to the file.

`// code that generates json data  
fs.writeFileSync(FILEPATH, JSON.stringify(jsonData));`

Only the above code I am doing, and the format for the json is specified as above.

I am also not able to reproduce this issue, one of my client is facing this issue.

Comment: The "corrupt file data" you show in your question is perfectly valid JSON. What's wrong with it? (BTW, please edit the question itself. Posting code into the comments is not useful.)

Comment: Updated with incorrect data, I also expects some other fields like key which is ID for me and details like name along with metadata.